# How to echo the first element from an array that it's located in another array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have tried the following:

```
    $social = array("https://www.google.com/","http://www.facebook.com/","https://www.twitter.com/", "http://www.linkedin.com/', "http://www.forrst.com/", "http://www.dribbble.com/");

    $this->settings['google'] = array(
        'title'   => __( 'Google' ),
        'desc'    => __( 'This is a description for the text input.' ),
        'std'     => .$social[1].'user1', // here i am trying to do https://www.google.com/user1
        'type'    => 'text',
        'section' => 'social'
    );
```

But I get the error `syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ')'`

Comment: Even the syntax highlighter in StackOverflow marks your mistake.

Comment: @CMate, why not point Adrian to it? - After linkedin.com you have a single quote, which should be a double quote.

Comment: @FWijmans, the sample code is only like 7 lines, and the mistake is shown so visibly by the syntax highlighter, that I thought it was not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need to close your `http://www.linkedin.com/` string with a `"` not a `'`, because it was opened with a `"`. (NB this should be picked up by your text editor's syntax highlighting, start using one)
- In PHP (and most others), the first array element should be referred to as `0` not `1`.
- Remove that `.` before `$social[0]`
- (Whitespace is free, don't be afraid to use it to make code more readable, and maybe easier to spot bugs. If not for yourself then for people on SO)

Try:

```
$social = array(
    "https://www.google.com/",
    "http://www.facebook.com/",
    "https://www.twitter.com/", 
    "http://www.linkedin.com/", 
    "http://www.forrst.com/", 
    "http://www.dribbble.com/"
);

$this->settings['google'] = array(
    'title'   => __( 'Google' ),
    'desc'    => __( 'This is a description for the text input.' ),
    'std'     => $social[0] . 'user1',
    'type'    => 'text',
    'section' => 'social'
);
```

---

Also, just to throw you another possibility in case you hadn't thought of it, you can make cleaner code using an *associative array*:

```
$social = array(
    "google" => "https://www.google.com/",
    "facebook" => "http://www.facebook.com/",
    // etc
);
```

Then refer to them as `$social["google"]` and `$social["facebook"]` instead of `$social[0]` and `$social[1]`.

Comment: Tried with associative but through out the error `Undefined Constant google` and went with $social[0] and it's ok. Thank you it solved my problem.

Comment: @Adrian You're welcome. `Undefined constant` will mean you forgot to put `"` marks around the word `google`... just because it's an array key, you still need to indicate that it's a string not a constant by using `"`. Start using search engines more – a quick Google for *php undefined constant* would've told you this in seconds :)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close your string correctly, in line 1.
Your wrote `"http://www.linkedin.com/'`, use `"http://www.linkedin.com/"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$social[1] + 'user1';`

becuase `$social[1]` is a string and does not have the property of 'user1'

Comment: Concatenation in PHP is "." not "+".

Comment: But the concatenation at the starting of the std value is unnecessary.

Comment: ...And object properties are `->` not `.`